# Duolingo typo "Wie bist du in mein Zimmer gekommen?"

Tags: grammar, preposition

I excercise German with the  Duolingo app from time to time, and today I think I found a typo in one of the excercises:
"Wie bist du in mein Zimmer gekommen?"

I was taught that "in" is a dative preposition which accepts a dative conjugation, thus making it: "Wie bist du in meinem Zimmer gekommen?"

So my question is whether it was just a tiny typo or some special case where it doesn't have to get the dative case?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that the dative-translation could (colloquially) be understood as: "How did you climax in my room?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duolingo is correct here. The preposition "in" can demand the accusative as well, and that isn't even a special case. It goes with the dative if it answers a "Wo?" or "Wann?" question, but the accusative for a "Wohin?" question. In the example you could think of "Wohin bist Du gekommen? - In das Zimmer.", so it's the accusative here.

**Other examples**:

> Er trinkt in der Kneipe ein Bier. (Wo? - dative)
>   Er ist in die Kneipe gegangen. (Wohin? - accusative)
>   In den Ferien fährt sie nach Frankreich. (Wann? - dative)

Other prepositions that demand either dative or accusative are "auf" and "an".

Answer (score 7):

The preposition *in* requires either the dative (when asking *where*) or the accusative (when asking *where / whither*). (German) in can mean both (English) in as well as into:

> Ich gehe im (= in dem) Wald = I walk in the forest. (I am already there.)
>
> Ich gehe in den Wald = I walk into the forest. (I am currently outside of it.)

As an additional aside, German *kommen* has the exact same meaning as "to come" in English, including all sexual connotations. *Wie bist Du in meinem Zimmer gekommen?* (How did you come in my room?) would be -- well, unintentionally funny, at the very least.

Comment: Your last example does not work properly. In German you would have to say *Wie bist Du in mein Zimmer gekommen.* and in English *How did you come into my room.* So there would be a difference to the sexual one. Even though connotations work for *(to) come* and *kommen* in general